# Reset iOS Simulator application data to run app for first time

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I just finished writing some code that checks if it is the first time the app is running then display a message, if it is not the first time then display another message..

How do you reset the simulator on Xcode so that I can test the app when it runs the first time?

I tried cleaning the build folder but it didn't work..

Answer (score 156, accepted):

In the iOS Simulator, press **iOS Simulator** in the menu at the top of the screen, and press '**Reset Content and Settings...**'.  This will clear the entire simulator.

Or, on the home screen of the simulator, uninstall the app in the same way you would on a physical device, by pressing and holding on the application icon until an '**x**' appears in the top left, and press the 'x', and select '**Delete**' from the alert view. This will clear all data associated with a single app.

Then do a clean, build and run.

Edit:

As of Xcode 11+ Simulator, this is under Device > Erase All Content and Settings

Comment: "Reset content and settings" should be as a last resort.  It wipes the entire simulator, causing its copy of iOS to take a long way to start up.  And it wipes all the database, including any images you may have added to its photo library, etc.  Deleting the app is much faster and only wipe's the app's content.

Comment: It depends on what type of data you're trying to erase. For example, if you're trying to remove 3rd-party login credentials that the app is relying on, then deleting just the app wouldn't suffice. However if that's not the case, then removing the app as @DavidC. suggested works perfectly.

Comment: **Update:** Changed to **Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings...**

Comment: Update: Changed to Device > Erase All Content and Settings

Answer (score 47):

The correct way to do this in Xcode is: (Simulator must be shut down first)

```bash
xcrun simctl shutdown <device UDID> && xcrun simctl erase <device UDID>
```

or

```bash
xcrun simctl shutdown all && xcrun simctl erase all
```

To find out the UDID use:

```bash
xcrun simctl list
```

Comment: Note, the simulator must be shutdown for this to work. Meaning the Simulator>Reset Contents and Settings... option kind of makes this command redundant

Answer (score 26):

Currently (Simulator Version 10.0), you can do it the following way:

Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings...

[image: The screenshot of the way to reset Simulator]

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers are how to delete an app, or how to erase all simulator content and settings. If you want to delete just content and settings for specific simulator app find the following folder and delete it:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE_UDID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APP_UDID}
```

Where {DEVICE_UDID} is identifier for specific simulator and {APP_UDID} is identifier for specific app.

Comment: How do you find the APP_UDID?

Answer (score 4):

@Tim's answer is probably easier for interactive usage.

We use scripts for automated testing and delete the simulator's data directory to ensure it's clean. The simulator will re-create basic information when it restarts.

Delete the following:

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/${simulator.version}`

Comment: If I remember correctly. The path changed in latest iOS 8 simulators.

Comment: Looks like the path is _~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices_ in Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 3):

Don't really know if this is the best way but following is working for me:

first kill all working Simulators with

`killall Simulator 2>&- && sleep 5 || true`

afterwards reset all devices with

`xcrun simctl erase all`

ps.: I'm working with **XCode 8**

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use for application running in iOS Simulator. Clear only application data folder.

```
rm -r `xcrun simctl get_app_container <DEVICE_UDID> <app bundle> data`
```

Note: the command will delete the whole folder, so be sure to copy its contents if you need it beforehand

Comment: breakingtesting, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: updated answer so it contains full solution

Comment: Add a warning that this will delete all data in this folder. Maybe use a `mv` instead of `rm` and provide a way to restore the folder if needed.

Comment: this is perfect. Allows to clean data of the app without restarting simulator. Just restart the app. Time saver, thanks!