# Class implemented in both Derived Data and Application (iOS, Google Drive SDK)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-drive-api

I'm currently using Google Drive SDK in my iOS app (Xcode 9, Swift 4). After manual linking of framework to my app I've got this warning (appears in console after app run):

> objc[9082]: Class GTMSessionFetcher is implemented in both
>   /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app_name-some
>   letters/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTLR.framework/GTLR
>   (0x1083eb628)

and

> /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/some_numbers_and_letters/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/some_numbers_and_letters/app_name.app/app_name
>   (0x106a34658). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

What may solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can try clean project, [delete Derrived Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) and [Clean Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195859/reset-ios-simulator-application-data-to-run-app-for-first-time).

It is a first that you can try to resolve this issue.

Comment: Tried this, no effect