# XCODE - linker command failed with exit code 1 - since xcode update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have recently updated my xcode and since doing so I have the following error.

[image]

I am not sure why this has all of a sudden appeared? Any help would be fantastic.

Thank you

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512823/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-after-xcode-8-0-update

Comment: Have you tried to delete Derived data and clean project?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the delay in replying I have only worked on this this evening.

Comment: @Rob No problem! You can mark my answer as correct if it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try clean project, [delete Derrived Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) and [Clean Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195859/reset-ios-simulator-application-data-to-run-app-for-first-time).

It is a first that you can try to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps -

1. Press `"Cmd+Shift+K"` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` in terminal
3. Open the project and `re-build` it

And make sure to add necessary framework to your project. Check all third party party framework and search its required framework for support. Hope this will solve your problem.