# iOS Simulator: How to clear cache of an app instead of entire phone?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

As the title already states, I want to clear the cache and all data of an app, but not everything on the actual iOS Simulator itself. All I can find on StackOverflow is posts like these:

[Reset iOS Simulator application data to run app for first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195859/reset-ios-simulator-application-data-to-run-app-for-first-time)

Where it tells me to reset the entire phone which takes quite a bit of time. I can clear the cache on the actual iPhone, I can't fathom why I wouldn't be able to on the simulator, it feels so basic.

Comment: You can long press the app to delete it as you would on the device, if that’s what you mean. That cleans the entire sandbox for the app.

Comment: True, but reinstalling the app takes a long time. I don't want to uninstall anything, I just want to clear the cache

Comment: Reinstalling doesn’t take significantly longer than a launch but maybe your app is big? Run recursive deletes on the relevant folders using FileManager.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xcrun simctl get_app_container <device> <bundleid> data` to get the path to your app's data container.

You can navigate to that directory and delete whatever content you want to delete.

Comment: Use _booted_ command controls if you want to clear the cache of an app with simulator active booted.

`xcrun simctl get_app_container booted <bundleid> data`

https://www.iosdev.recipes/simctl/#locate-an-app-bundle-app-data-or-app-group-data